# Can I use scipy-approx_fprime() for tensorflow operations?

Tags: python, tensorflow, scipy, computer-vision

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.approx_fprime.html

```
from scipy import optimize
forward_module = tf.load_op_library('./build/libforwardcu.so')
f2 = tf.tanh(tf.conv2d(x1, w)+b)
f1 = tf.tanh(tf.conv2d(x2, w)+b)
def func(x):
    forward_module.forward(x,f2, disps, 1, 0)
    return loss
optimize.approx_fprime(x, func, 1e-6)
```

Would `approx_fprime` automatically detect the derivation rules from tensorflow (costs, loss)?

I mean that if the function is `f(x)=x^2`, then the derivation would be detected by scipy `f'(x)=2x`. Of course by a neural network is a lot more effort and I want to avoid to do that by hand...

Comment: scipy does not know anything about tf. Either your function is a valid one and producing a scalar output (then scipy's numdiff works) or it's not (and it won't work). It's also hard to understand your motivation to mix automatic-differentiation (not part of scipy) and numerical-differentiation here. Furthermore, your function might be incomplete defined (w, b).

Comment: this above is just a pseudo code...   I wrote a tf.op and want to check it if it works correctly. Therefore, it is a general question... and I want to know if it works...  
So, I have to write the forward pass by hand instead of using `tf.conv`.

Comment: The function just does what's specified in it's docs. If tf is used internally, it's transparent to scipy and does not matter if input & output is correct (no introspection at all i would say; you can also read an image or do other stuff... not that it's useful). But it strikes me odd to use tf internally (which supports autodiff) to do numdiff on the outside (except for some crazy case where you want to speed up cost-eval using tf; but can't afford / don't want to use autodiff).